# zend send Json helper

Tags: json, zend-framework

I'm trying to send Json text using `$this_helper->json->sendJson('Ôtre'=>'Être'`
but the problem is the special caracters not recongnized. how i can force zend to send appropriat Json.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with some PHP Versions when encoding Special chars. You can overship the problem by setting the following:

```
Zend_Json::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder = true;
```